# Building a geographical location filter app in Django

Tags: django, geodjango

I would like to create a market place like app with Djano as the backend server, where users can buy/sell items. In the app I would like have to a feature related to geographic region of a user. Such as, to filter out items in a given specific miles of radius.

Example use case:

- User uploads an item, get the gps cordinates from their mobile and store in db.
- User can search item, also filter to only get items in X miles radius.

For this feature

1. I have looked at GeoDjango. But it seems like I need to extend the postgresql database to use it, also by using the `postgis` engine.
2. I have also looked at the Haversine formula for nearby queries.
3. There is also an option for multiple database support.

But I have some initial doubts before proceeding and your insights would really help me alot. Could you please help me with this queries:

1. I will have to store user data and some other data including the geo location. Will there be any difference/side effects between `postgresql_psycopg2` and `postgis`, to store all the data in one single db?
2. For my simple use case would you rather prefer to go with the Haversine formula? Or integrating GeoDjango will help me lot in the future?
3. Or having a multiple database support be better for me or it will be an over head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

point 
1. postgresql_psycopg2 and postgis is difference that posgis has inbuilt functionality for the location distance and radius calculation, so postgis is good to go.

2. For multiple database it depends up on how many user you will have, for initial phase of project you can got with one db, in future you can improve that.